# TweenLite Typescript import

Tags: npm, typescript, gsap

I downloaded the GSAP package by npm and now I want to import TweenLite class to my app by TypeScript. It can be done by importing all GSAP by writing `require('gsap');` and it works well. But in TypeScript it doesn't work.
I want to do it like this: `import TweenLite from 'gsap';`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26505153/2918518). Actually if you want to do this then you need write definitions for library. The answer from the link provide link to git repository that contains what I was needed. You can find it [here](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped).

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install --save-dev gsap
npm install --save-dev @types/gsap
```

in your ts file, import gsap

```
import {TweenLite} from "gsap";
```

and in your method you can write

```
let photo = document.getElementById("photo");
TweenLite.to(photo, 2, {width:"200px", height:"550px"});
```

if you have a div with and ID of photo

Comment: When I do so I get an error "import declaration in namespace cannot reference a module". If I move import out of module then many errors inside  module appears