# How to use Phoenix Channels / Sockets in an Angular 2 app?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, phoenix-framework, brunch

I have a backend built with Elixir / Phoenix and a frontend built with Angular 2 (Typescript, Brunch,io for building, ES6). I now want to use Phoenix Channels. And I'm a bit desperate trying to use the Phoenix Javascript Client in my frontend.

When I install https://www.npmjs.com/package/phoenix-js via `npm install phoenix-js` and then try to inject it into a service in angular like this:

```
import { Socket } from "phoenix-js";
```

I always get the error `Cannot find module phoenix-js` during compilation.

I'm a bit stuck and every hint on how to get this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274278/reference-javascript-file-inside-typescript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:** I'm going to leave the old answer below - even though it is a bit emberassing. Getting everything to work and using the most recent version of the Phoenix JS Client with Angular 2 was even easier than I thought and I was just terribly confused.

The Phoenix JS client has been extracted as an npm package and can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phoenix). Install it with `npm install --save phoenix`. Then load it as additional dependency. In my setup with SystemJS it was just a matter of adding the necessary configuration:

```
import { join } from 'path';
import { SeedConfig } from './seed.config';
import { InjectableDependency } from './seed.config.interfaces';

export class ProjectConfig extends SeedConfig {
  PROJECT_TASKS_DIR = join(process.cwd(), this.TOOLS_DIR, 'tasks', 'project');

  constructor() {
    super();
    // this.APP_TITLE = 'Put name of your app here';
    let additional_deps: InjectableDependency[] = [
      // {src: 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', inject: 'libs'},
      // {src: 'lodash/lodash.min.js', inject: 'libs'},
      {src: 'phoenix/priv/static/phoenix.js', inject: 'libs'}
    ];

    const seedDependencies = this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES;

    this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES = seedDependencies.concat(additional_deps);
  }
}
```

Now we have it in the global scope and just need to use `declare var` in the Angular 2 service typescript file where we want to use it. Here was where I made a crucial mistake. I tried to access `Socket` directly and therefor used `declare var Socket: any`. Which always led to the error `Socket is undefined.` But [this issue](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/906) got me in the right direction: If you use the transpiled ES5 version (and not ES6) you have to use `Phoenix.Socket` (because of namespacing I guess).

So this is how my service looks like now:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare var Phoenix: any;

@Injectable()
export class PhoenixChannelService {

  socket: any;

  constructor() {
    this.socket = new Phoenix.Socket("ws://localhost:4000/socket", {
      logger: ((kind, msg, data) => { console.log(`${kind}: ${msg}`, data) }),
      transport: WebSocket
    });
    this.socket.connect();
  }
}
```

Now everything works like a charm.

If you don't want to install the client via npm, there is a more basic way: Just get the [latest version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/master/priv/static/phoenix.js) of the JS Client from GitHub from `/priv/static`, store it in the folder where you keep your static assets and include it directly in your `index.html`:

```
<script src="/path/to/static/js/phoenix.js"></script>
```

The rest stays the same.

Note: If you want to use it with typescript type definitions, [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phoenix-ts) npm package might be a good starting point - even though it is a bit old.

---

**Old and embarrassing answer:** So I think I figured it out. Writing my own definition file wasn't an option. And since all the documented code on how to use the phoenix client is in ES6 I got stuck including the transpiled ES5 version directly in my index.html. But the first clue was [this article](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/).

I then found [this issue](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/827) on GitHub which is about extracting the Phoenix Client. Via this I then found [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phoenix-js), which is a bit outdated but seems to work. I install it with `npm insall --save phoenix-js` and then load the dependency in my project. Since my Angular App is based on [this seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/) it goes into my project definition (and make sure to load the Globals version of the phoenix client:

```
import { join } from 'path';
import { SeedConfig } from './seed.config';
import { InjectableDependency } from './seed.config.interfaces';

export class ProjectConfig extends SeedConfig {
  PROJECT_TASKS_DIR = join(process.cwd(), this.TOOLS_DIR, 'tasks', 'project');

  constructor() {
    super();
    // this.APP_TITLE = 'Put name of your app here';
    let additional_deps: InjectableDependency[] = [
      // {src: 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', inject: 'libs'},
      // {src: 'lodash/lodash.min.js', inject: 'libs'},
      {src: 'phoenix-js/dist/glob/main.js', inject: 'libs'}
    ];

    const seedDependencies = this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES;

    this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES = seedDependencies.concat(additional_deps);
  }
}
```

Now I can use it in my angular 2 service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare var Socket: any;
declare var Channel: any;

@Injectable()
export class PhoenixChannelService {

  socket: any;
  channel: any;

  constructor() {

    this.socket = new Socket("/socket", {
      logger: ((kind, msg, data) => { console.log(`${kind}: ${msg}`, data) })
    });
    this.socket.connect({user_id: "123"});

  }

}
```

Depending on your build process (I use gulp) and other factors you might have to adapt. But I hope this provides some help to other people stuck with this issue.

Edit: [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phoenix) is the official extracted JS client for Phoenix. But I didn't get it to work in my setup, probably because of Typescript.